# Working on jsfiddle.net but not on my Laptop?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Kindly look at http://jsfiddle.net/fLd5T/.

This simple javaScript code running fine on jsfiddle.net is not working on my laptop.

Here is the code on my laptop:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript">
// setup
var goal = "fix the bug";
var date2 = new Date();
var diff = 0;
var active = true;http://jsfiddle.net/#save
var data = '{"goals": [{"goal":"' + goal + '","duedate":"'
    + date2 + '","noofdays":"' + diff + '","active":"'
    + active + '"}]}';
localStorage.setItem("goals",data);

// test
var goalsStr = localStorage.getItem("goals");
var goalsObj = JSON.parse(goalsStr); 
for (i=0; i<goalsObj.goals.length; i++) {
  //if(goal==goalsObj.goals[i].goal) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
        "The goal is " + JSON.stringify(goalsObj.goals[i])));
  }
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

javaScript is enabled in my browser.

Why is it so? What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: check your browser settings, is javascript enable ?

Comment: @mehdi Yes. Ofcourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I check your code I see 2 things:

First at line 18 the `if` statement is commented out, but the closing `}` is not which leads to a syntax error.

The other thing is that **you're trying to access `document.body` before it's been created**. You should move your javascript code (the entire `<script>...</script>`) inside `<body></body>` instead of `<head></head>`.

You can also add `window.onload = function () { ... }` around your javascript code.
It's working on jsfiddle because that's what it's actually done there.